# Docker with a virtualized software firewall ahead

Tags: firewall, docker

I'm currently working on a Docker setup and here is how I decided to think it :

- An Ubuntu host, which host :

  - A *KVM* of an *OpenBSD* configured and acting as a firewall :

    - The firewall will have it's own public IP
  - Some Docker containers which are behind the firewall

Here is a scheme to summarize it :
[image: Scheme]

**My first question is** : Is it a good idea to put a firewall in front of Docker's container ?

**The second one is** : If it is a good idea, can I use an *OpenvSwitch* switch to bridge container and vm on it (then make it accessible on the web by NAT) ?

Comment: I would consider using FreeBSD (which support `pf` and `bhyve`) to host a Linux guest which would run Docker, which might be a little more robust, I could imagine.

Answer (score 1):

you can control the traffic of your containers in your host using iptables,  i don't see the need for use openbsd in this case

Comment: The OpenBSD will also host a VPN. And I feel more secured with OpenBSD.

Comment: Linux is not secure from your point of view?

Comment: This isn't a question of a point view, I prefer pf than IpTables. I find OpenBSD better when it comes to play a firewall role.